# ppa repositories removed for raring. How do you install packages using old-releases.ubuntu.com

Tags: apt, updates, package-management

Using a Ubuntu/Debian variant (Navigatrix) release based on Raring, which is no longer supported in the Ubuntu Repositories. 
Current etc/apt/source.list is:

```
deb (http removed) pa.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted universe multiverse
deb (http removed) pa.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb (http removed) pa.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb (http removed) security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb (http removed) archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner
deb (http removed) extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main
```

Need to install a couple of Gimp libraries (libgimp2.0-dev and libpcre3-dev) but attempts to apt-get install result in the expected 404 errors.

Know packages have been moved to old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/ but don't know how to rewrite etc/apt/source.list to point at the packages?

Updating to newer release is not currently an option.

Comment: Even if updating is not an option, you will find the information you need in the duplicate and related. (If not, please state what is missing.)